# LOGO is not mobile responsive

Tags: magento-1.9, theme, mobile

I have  updated the logo  of the website and it is not working on the mobile.
I have searched a lot on the web but i didn't got any solution. Please help me in resolving this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to `app/design/frontend/{package}/{theme}/template/page/html/header.phtml` or the custom header of your theme and add `img-responsive` class to your logo like this:

```
...title="<?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?>" class="logo img-responsive">...
```

Comment: Is my answer solved your problem ?

Comment: yes @prince but due to reputation issue i am unable to upvote it

Comment: You just have to accept it ;)

Comment: @Prince  echo 
    '<style>.top-container 
          { background:url("/skin/frontend/default/theme327k/images/aus-bg.jpg");  
              background-size: cover;
             }
    
        </style>';
  How can i give responsive here?

Comment: `background-size: cover;` do the trick

Comment: Try also : `background-size:contain;
   background-repeat:no-repeat;`